# How to render Arabic strings in Bottle framework?

Tags: python, utf-8, arabic, bottle

I am learning Bottle framework and new to Python. Just stumbled upon this difficulty. When I write a simple method to return a an Arabic string like:

```
@route('/hello')
def hello():
    return u'سلام'
```

I get this error message in the terminal:

> SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xd8' in file hello.py on line 15,
>   but no encoding declared; see http://www.python.org/peps/pep-0263.html
>   for details

I have imported all from bottle and tried adding other methods mentioned in the [docs](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/tutorial.html#installation)  where it talks about "Changing the Default Encoding" however I was unable to resolve the issue. So I appreciate your hints.

Comment: What do you exactly do to get this error message ???

Comment: follow the link in the error message.

Comment: The errors shows up in the terminal when I run the script: 'python hello.py'

Comment: at least you have to do some print hello(), to get the error ?

Comment: @rocksportrocker: This a framework, and does not need 'print' to render strings.

Answer (score 7):

Here is my code for testing:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from bottle import *

@route('/hello')
def hello():
    return u'سلام'

run(host='127.0.0.1', port=8080,reloader=True)
```

In my editor, I choose File > Save As..., then select Unicode (UTF-8) as Text Encoding, and saved as hello.py

Then download [the lastest version of bottle.py from github](https://github.com/defnull/bottle/raw/master/bottle.py), and put it in the same folder(e.g. bottle-test) with hello.py

Run it, and seems no problems at all.

```
~$ python --version
Python 2.6.7
~$ cd bottle-test
bottle-test$ python hello.py
```

[image: Result in browser]

Comment: amazing best answer i didn't know bottle framework , so cool so easy :D thanks شكر لك

Answer (score 5):

just add

```
# -*- coding: whatever-encoding-you-use -*-
```

on the top of your file

Comment: you probably use UTF-8 (I hope so). So write it instead of `whatever-encoding-you-use`

Comment: According to the docs Bottle's default encoding is utf-8 and my editor's default is utf-8 too. That's what make this problem so weird for me.

Comment: This isn't a question of Bottle though, it's a question of the Python compiler (which gets first shot at the file).  You need to tell the compiler what encoding your file is in, otherwise it will assume it's Latin-1.

Answer (score 2):

Save your file as utf-8 and insert

```
#encoding: utf-8
```

as the first line of your file

Comment: SyntaxError: invalid syntax. According to the docs Utf-8 is the default encoding.

Comment: @qliq: Do you have your issue resolved? If yes, you probably should accept one of the answers. If no, can you please elaborate on where you get SyntaxError _in a comment?_ Maybe provide an additional snippet of your code in the question itself.

Answer (score 2):

At the top of your script, enter this:

```
# encoding: utf-8
```

The thing is, your script might run with the latin1 encoding (ISO 8859-1), which is limited compared to UTF-8

Comment: Maybe, but when you run the script, the Python Interpreter doesn't know if you use an IDE or Gedit which uses UTF-8 when you type your code. When you run the script and it sees that it use UTF-8 it will set it, or it will use the default Latin1 (maybe not for python3 and more, I'm not sure)